# How to tell Rails to unload a controller (in Rspec test)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In a controller test i want to check if new relic aspects are defined as expected. To test it i'm doing something like:

```
describe 'newrelic_ignore' do
  let(:load_class) do
    load Rails.root.join("app/controllers/foo_controller.rb")
  end

  before do
    Project::Application.send(:remove_const, 'FooController')
    stub_const('NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ControllerInstrumentation', Module.new)
  end

  it "should inject newrelic_ignore" do
    Module.any_instance.should_receive(:newrelic_ignore).with(no_args())
    load_class
  end
end
```

It seems that i'm trying to remove the constant at the wrong place resulting in:

```
pry(main)> Project::Application.send(:remove_const, 'FooController')
NameError: constant Project::Application::FooController not defined
```

Can anyone give me a hint there these reside? Additionally if someone knows a more convinient way to test this i would appreciate to hear about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Object.send(:remove_const, :FooController)
```